# Summarize a column with multiple boolean columns

Tags: database, sqlite, group-by, conditional-aggregation

I have a sqlite database containing a table who looks like this, to store many to many relation :

| ID_1 | ID_2 | TOOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | x |
| 1 | 2 | y |
| 1 | 3 | x |
| 1 | 3 | z |
| 2 | 3 | x |
| 2 | 3 | y |
| 2 | 3 | z |

The two first columns contains ID of pairs of features, and the last one contains the name a tool that is related to these feature. A same pair of features can be associated with multiple tools.

I'm looking for a set of query to summarize this table so it looks like this, without modifying the database structure.

| ID_1 | ID_2 | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Displaying a new column for each unique TOOL name, containing 0 if the tool is not associated with the pair of ID, and 1 if it is.
And having only one row per pair of ID.

Is there a combination of command that allow to do that ?

I tried using multiple CASE WHERE statements, but I'm stuck with this kind of results (here with a simplified example) :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
     ID_1 integer NOT NULL,
     ID_2 integer NOT NULL,
     tool string NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO test_table (ID_1, ID_2, tool)
VALUES
    (1,2,"x"), (1,2,"y"), (1,3,"x"), (1,3,"z"), (2,3,"x"), (2,3,"y"), (2,3,"z")
    
    
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN tool == "x" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS x,
    CASE WHEN tool == "y" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS y,
    CASE WHEN tool == "z" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS z
FROM test_table
```

| ID_1 | ID_2 | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Is the combination (1,2) different than (2,1)?

Comment: No, (1,2) have the same meaning as (2,1). But in principle, this should not happen.

Comment: Is there a way to consider (1,2) == (2,1) to sort of merge the results ?

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/diXNH9Kxg5NMxvd1NNxpH/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ID_1, ID_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tool = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) x,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tool = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) y,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tool = 'z' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) z
FROM test_table
GROUP BY ID_1, ID_2;
```

which, for SQLite, can be simplified:

```
SELECT ID_1, ID_2,
       MAX(tool = 'x') x,
       MAX(tool = 'y') y,
       MAX(tool = 'z') z
FROM test_table
GROUP BY ID_1, ID_2;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/diXNH9Kxg5NMxvd1NNxpH/1).